# "to" argument must be a list or tuple in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a bug like in subject of this question:

```
"to" argument must be a list or tuple
```

I want to create a email form and I can't find a error. Maybe someone help me?

My files are:
**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class WyslijEmail(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    message = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from .forms import WyslijEmail


def kontakt(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = WyslijEmail()
    else:
        form = WyslijEmail(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(name,subject,email,message, ['admin@gmail.com',])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return render('Niewlasciwe cos tam')
            return redirect('sukces')
    return render(request,'bajki/kontakt.html', {'form':form})

def sukces(request):
    return render('Sukces udało sie')
```

**kontakt.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Wyślij wiadomość"></p>
</form>
```

What I must define to fix this problem?

Os so I updated my files and now theyare looking like this:
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .forms import WyslijEmail


def kontakt(request):
    sent = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WyslijEmail(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email,['login@gmail.com'])
            sent = True
    else:
        form = WyslijEmail()
    return render(request,'bajki/kontakt.html', {'form':form, 'sent': sent})
```

But its a second problem. When I trying to sent email from page the system responded me a error like this:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /kontakt/
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials h63sm1453929ljf.36 - gsmtp')
```

I change the settings in my google account to accept the all emails. I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: You should post the traceback of the error

Comment: Try removing the comma in the to list ['admin@gmail.com',]

Comment: Rakesh I removed it, but this same problem still I have

Comment: You've issued another problem so you better create a new question. Anyway, most probably problems is wrong username and password for sender (SMTP settings in `settings.py`)

Comment: Also yes, name argument is something wrong. You only can pass subject, message, from and to emails, as briancaffey wrote

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to structure `send_mail` from the [`Django Documentation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/email/#send-mail):

```
send_mail(subject, 
          message, 
          from_email, 
          recipient_list, 
          fail_silently=False, 
          auth_user=None, 
          auth_password=None, 
          connection=None, 
          html_message=None)
```

You should change the arguments in your `send_mail` function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your **[send_mail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#send-mail)** method should have four arguments.

```
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
EX:
subject == string
message == string
from_email == string
recipient_list == list
```

Looks like you have additional argument '*name*'. And you have not mentioned the from_email argument.

Comment: Rakesh I change this and I update my problem. Maybe You know how to solve this problem with gmail?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is at the send_mail() function.
I would advise you save your form.clean_data in a variable for reusability
i.e `cd = form.clean_data.`
Then for the send_mail pass the parameter correctly, and wrap your cd['to'] in a list

```
send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myblog.com', [cd['to']])
```

Answer (score -1):

The issues in your updated code is that the to_email argument takes a list. Instead of writing `['login@gmail.com']`, you need to write `['login@gmail.com',]` with a comma to make it into a list.

Comment: List is always a list in Python, regardless to commas in it. You only need to have at least one comma inside `(` and `)` to make it tuple, because parentheses can have other meaning. Square brackets in this context may only have one meaning which is list literal, so don't need to add comma